# Multiple conditional where clauses not working in Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a function that is supposed to use a combination of filters set by the user to fetch information from a table (or no filters at all).

Keep in mind I'm not trying to override filters here, the query should dynamically add or remove filters depending on the ones set client-side by the user.

The filters work well individually, but when setting multiple of them, the query doesn't fetch the correct data at all. I'm still unable to figure out what the criteria for the incorrect data being fetched is.

The only filters that seem to work in combination with others are `date_from` and `date_to`.

This is the function:

```
public function getReport(Request $request)
{
    // Convertir fechas a formato correcto
    $request->date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $request->date_from)));
    $request->date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $request->date_to)));
    
    $query = Ticket::all();

    $query->when(isset($request->date_from), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('date_created', '>=', $request->date_from);
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->date_to), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('date_created', '<=', $request->date_to);
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->user), function ($q) use ($request) {
        return $q->where('user', $request->user);
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->paid), function ($q) use ($request) {      
        if ($request->paid === true) {
            return $q->whereNotNull('paid');
        } else {
            return $q->whereNull('paid');
        }
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->informed), function ($q) use ($request) {       
        return $q->where('informed', $request->informed);
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->endorsement), function ($q) use ($request) {       
        if ($request->endorsement === true) {
            $query->where('policy', '<', 1);
        } else {
            $query->where('policy', '>', 1);
        }
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->duplicate), function ($q) use ($request) {       
        return $q->where('duplicate', $request->duplicate);
    });
    $query->when(isset($request->active), function ($q) use ($request) {        
        return $q->where('active', $request->active);
    });
    
    return response()->json($query, $this->success_status);
}
```

I've tested the `$request` payload multiple times and there's no issues with the information coming client-side.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but try checking if field is not empty: `if (!empty($request->user))` or use has() `if($request->has('user'))`. Also take a look at using when() conditional clauses to clean up the if statements: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Log the sql query and see if it produced the desired statement. It might be easier to debug from there.

Comment: all your `=== false` checks will never be hit because the previous `if` condition would be false, btw

Comment: Updated the function based on your comments. @user3532758 I'm trying to use `->toSql()` to output the query and syntax seems correct, aside from a `?` replacing all variables

Comment: Something to note in the current state of the function is that it doesn't seem to enter a single `when()` right now, why would that be? I checked the payload and it's fine.

Comment: instead of isset, use `$request->has()` and see if it workds. and `?` is placeholder to bind the variables in the prepared statement. Alternatively you can do `DB::enableQueryLog()` to log the query sent to mysql and the bindings array.

Comment: Tried both `$request->has()` and `$request->filled()` as alternatives but still, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try given solution for you problem.

```
$query = Ticket::all();
if ($request->filled('user')) {
   $user = $request->get('user');
   $query->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
       $query->where('user', $user);
   });
}
```

**Note:** if it is working perfect then you can add all request parameter according.

Answer (score 0):

First note:

```
$query = Ticket::all();
```

In this case $query is not Eloquent query but Laravel Collection.

Another note:

$request is not regular php object with properties, so you have to use **->has()**, **->filled()** instead of **empty()** or **isset()**

Your ->data_to and ->data_from are working, cause you have overwritten those values in the beginning, so they become regular object properties.

Also, I would simplify some parts of your code:

```
$query->when(isset($request->duplicate), function ($q) use ($request) {       
    return $q->where('duplicate', $request->duplicate);
});
```

I would use this construction instead to save some lines:

```
$query->where('duplicate', $request->get('duplicate', false));
```

Second param of ->get is default value. If it is not present in request you will get false anyway. So you don't have to care about param existence.

You can apply same logic to all other filters as well.

PS: I don't know your requirements, but this part seems suspicious to me:

```
$query->when(isset($request->endorsement), function ($q) use ($request) {       
    if ($request->endorsement === true) {
        $query->where('policy', '<', 1);
    } else {
        $query->where('policy', '>', 1);
    }
});
```

This code will never give 'policy' === 1;